# Search by conten_type in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, rubygems

I want to provide search functionality on the basis of spreadsheets, presentations, documents, images, videos etc ..

Are there any plugins or gems available for this type of functionality ? Any suggestions to provide this functionality ?

Comment: @mu database side. I have stored the content type of files in database. But looking for better solution how to handle this functionality. How the search should be on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem to upload and store your files. It stores content_type automatically, so you`ll have a possibility to search/filter by content type etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide indexed search functionality, why not integrate with [Apache Solr engine?](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sunspot](https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot) for integrating with Apache Solr. [Solr Cell](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler) which is integrated by default with latest Solr, allows you to index any type of Rich Text Documents.